# How and where does SSL signing apply to emails?

Tags: email, ssl, ssl-certificate, signing, mta

I am trying to find out how SSL signing of emails work and if it gets signed server side or MTA side? I know this is a bit vague maybe but any resources to read or documentation would help a lot :D

Like for example I use a ezComponents mail object to send a mail object to the MTA server. DO I have to sign the mail object inside of PHP by using something

OR

Does the signing happen on the sending server (MTA)?

Just to add some clarity, I would like to use this functionality to send secure emails to customers for their monthly statements and reports. But implementation is irrelevant at this stage, I am interested in docs and resources and wisdom from people that knows :D

**EDIT**: Okay so I am using S/MIME. does anybody have an idea how to do this? I can't find any good PHP examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL is a transport protocol, and there's no such thing as "SSL signing of e-mails". This is why you can't find anything.

Signing of e-mail is done using S/MIME standard. Signing is performed by the sender application using sender's X.509 certificate with a corresponding private key. *IF* the SMTP server has all certificates *with keys*, it can sign e-mail on behalf of the sender. This is sometimes used in corporate environments.

Comment: +1 Thx, this is why I love this site! I had no idea, and know I learned something new. So this standard is the way banks use it?

Comment: Signing/encrypting can also be done with PGP, not just S/MIME

Comment: @raticulin There's no such thing as "PGP", when talking about standards. There exists OpenPGP and it's application to MIME is called OpenPGP/MIME. It was popular a decade ago, but now it's almost never used and not supported out of the box by major mail applications.

Comment: @Eugene, by PGP, I referred to both PGP/MIME and OpenPGP generically. I work on a email archiving product so I can assure you that I see PGP (in some incarnation) used in real world.

Comment: @raticulin PGP Corporation legal department has different opinion regarding names that misuse their trademark ;). Also, we develop security components and I see the level of demand for various types or mail security (and other trends as well).

Comment: @Eugene I never said PGP was the prevalent way of signing, just that something else than S/MIME can, and is, used (even if at smaller scale)

Comment: Okay so I am using S/MIME. does anybody have an idea how to do this? I can't find any good PHP examples

Comment: @etbal posting the question in the comments doesn't work on SO. Please post a new question OR edit the existing question by appending an update (don't remove old text).

Answer (score 0):

Email signing happens in the client's MUA. All you need is to generate an S/MIME email message and send it using your MTA as a regular message.

Comment: What is MUA and MTA in this case?

Comment: MUA is a Mail User Agent, i.e. a program which is used to compose an email message. MTA is a Mail Transfer Agent, i.e. the program which delivers email message to its destination or to the next hop MTA. Usually your email client (or email web interface) is the MUA, and your provider's server is your MTA.